# Problems in making CLM files with DIVA-GIS

Tags: climate, diva-gis

I am fairly new to GIS softwares and this will be my first post here. I'm working with DIVA-GIS and was redirected here. I hope this is the correct place.

I am doing a research which involves ecological niche modeling for present and future climate scenarios. However, i am having some urgent problems with creating the `.clm` files for the predicted future climate.

I have downloaded the necessary data from WorldClim. I have followed the instructions from "Ramirez & Bueno, 2009, Working with climate data and niche modeling: Creation of bioclimatic variables", but DIVA GIS doesn't seem to want to create the files.

Basically, i open up the "Make CLM files" window in DIVA GIS, and have all the necessary 36 `.grd` files + the `alt.grd` required for the operation. I have correctly inserted the prefixes and ticked their boxes. As soon as I press "OK", these boxes automatically uncheck, the 36 files are not split into the "selected files" spaces present in the window, and the program only creates the single `climate.cli` files.

I have found this question being asked on the Internet but with no answer.

I have no idea how to solve the issue as everything seems to have been done correctly. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem… follow this guide from steps 5 and onwards if you have not already done so. 
http://www.ccafs-climate.org/downloads/docs/Ramirez_Bueno-Cabrera_2009_tutorial_bcvars_creation.pdf

The EXACT file naming is critical!!! In the upper file prefix window change the prefixes to “tmin_” for Tmin, “tmax_” for Tmax and “prec_” for Precipitation; Then rename each of the 36 files to match the prefix (ie. change tmin10_11.grd -> “tmin_10.grd"). So in the end you should have a folder with 36 grd and 36 gir files (tmin_1.grd, tmin_1.gri, tmin_2.grd, tmin_2.gri, ect. (NOT "tmin1_11.grd").

Another important consideration is file size and storage capacity. If you download and create monthly tmin values for each month at a 1km/1km resolution for the entire planet, Diva-GIS will just freeze out. I would suggest downloading and merging only the tiles you need… then follow steps to convert (BIL - > grd)

http://www.worldclim.org/formats

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 7.5 version... leave the "suffix" field blank. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above didn't help, please try my R package [prepCLMdata](https://github.com/DrKrisChan/prepclmdata)

Best of luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).